# How can I keep my relationship with an unproductive co-worker who makes me do twice the work?

Tags: colleagues, productivity

For the past few months, I have been working with a coworker who, although is smart and hardworking, tends to make me promises which he doesn't live up to. These might be trivial ones like coming early on a particular day, or major ones such as completing his part of the report sooner.

A few points:

- I'm not sure I'd categorize him as lazy, he does do work. Just not what I (or others) ask him to do. At times, he does nothing though.
- We have no personal problems.
- Reporting to the boss didn't help because he ended up telling me to "figure it out on my own"
- Talking to him yields more faulty promises "I was wrong in the past,  I promise to do it this time" but doesn't.
- I am not forcing my expectations on him, we cordially split the work justly.

Most of the times, I end up doing twice the work (his side and mine) just so that the clients stay happy. At times, he is apologetic and other times he acts as if nothings happened.

What can I do to try and get my co-worker to get his work done, without ruining our relationship?

Comment: I was going to say it's your boss's problem, not yours. But I see that (s)he's already made it yours. So you need to make it your boss's problem again (not sure how you sensibly do that though).

Comment: As formatted this question is not constructive.  What is the goal of "Handling" you coworker? The job is getting done, are you willing to sacrifice your personal relationship to get him to do his job? There are 10 ways I can come up with to handle this situation off the top of my head that lead to different outcomes and I have no way of guessing which is the right one for you based on this question.

Comment: Ideally, I'd want to get work done from him (& not overload myself) without screwing our personal relationship.

Comment: You should edit the question to include the desired outcome information.  "How do I change his behavior?" "How do I get things done despite his behavior?" "How do I get my boss to deal with it?" and "How do I get him fired?" are all different questions in this context, and will get different answers.

Comment: Try implementing some kind of Task List or Tracker to help them keep up with the requests. In addition, I find meeting regularly and going over open tasks is a great way to gently remind someone about a task they said they'd do, but haven't finished yet.

Comment: I have both voted to re-open and also change the title to "How to deal with an unproductive co-worker who makes me do twice the work?"

Comment: Quite easy: just do your work. If clients aren't happy, that's not your problem, since it's not your company. If the boss doesn't care, again, not your problem.

Comment: Since your boss didn't seem to think it was that important, neither should you.  Be sure to communicate though.  You should be giving some sort of project status.  In those detail the promises when made, then detail when not lived up to, if they affect you.  If they don't affect your part, then don't worry about it.  Have your part done and good.  I know it's a team effort, but when the teammates and the coach won't help, it's kind of out of your hand.

Answer (score 8):

[How to Win Friends and Influence People](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Win_Friends_and_Influence_People) has some ideas that you may want to consider:

> Fundamental Techniques in Handling People
>
> 1. Don't criticize, condemn, or complain.
> 2. Give honest and sincere appreciation.
> 3. Arouse in the other person an eager want.
> 4. Never show others that you are not interested in what they have to say.
>
> Six Ways to Make People Like You
>
> 1. Become genuinely interested in other people.
> 2. Smile.
> 3. Remember that a person's name is, to that person, the sweetest and most important sound in any language.
> 4. Be a good listener. Encourage others to talk about themselves.
> 5. Talk in terms of the other person's interest.
> 6. Make the other person feel important – and do it sincerely.
>
> Twelve Ways to Win People to Your Way of Thinking
>
> 1. The only way to get the best of an argument is to avoid it.
> 2. Show respect for the other person's opinions. Never say "You're Wrong."
> 3. If you're wrong, admit it quickly and emphatically.
> 4. Begin in a friendly way.
> 5. Start with questions to which the other person will answer yes.
> 6. Let the other person do a great deal of the talking.
> 7. Let the other person feel the idea is his or hers.
> 8. Try honestly to see things from the other person's point of view.
> 9. Be sympathetic with the other person's ideas and desires.
> 10. Appeal to the nobler motives.
> 11. Dramatize your ideas.
> 12. Throw down a challenge.
>
> Be a Leader: How to Change People Without Giving Offense or Arousing
>   Resentment
>
> 1. Begin with praise and honest appreciation.
> 2. Call attention to people's mistakes indirectly.
> 3. Talk about your own mistakes before criticizing the other person.
> 4. Ask questions instead of giving direct orders.
> 5. Let the other person save face.
> 6. Praise every improvement.
> 7. Give the other person a fine reputation to live up to.
> 8. Use encouragement. Make the fault seem easy to correct.
> 9. Make the other person happy about doing what you suggest.

To apply these points, I'd likely consider smiling, knowing a bit about that person, asking to get sufficient background, and being aware of when could I encourage things to praise the improvements when they come. While there may be the desire to "Shape up or ship out" this would likely create an adversarial relationship that will backfire. There is something to be said for respecting what the other person can provide as a way to see the situation different as Stephen Covey listed in his "7 Habits of Highly Effective People" that "seek first to understand then to be understood" where there is something to be said for how well do you know all the details from the other person's situation?